# What happens if you go bankrupt trying to pay the bank?

Tags: monopoly

Let's say I land on someone's hotel. I'm short in cash. So, I sell houses, mortgage everything, and am still short in cash. I am now out of the game and that player gets my money and mortgaged properties. If I remember right, they pay the 10% tax or unmortgage at that time. And the game continues.

Now, let's say I had just barely enough cash to pay them. I'm safe and still in the game. I've got nearly zero money and all my stuff is mortgaged. The next turn I land on chance/community chest/luxury tax/jail and I need to pay the bank. I cannot pay.

Who gets the properties? Do they disappear from the game? Go back for sale as mortgaged? Unmortgaged?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From my understanding they all go back to the bank. They all then actually got auctioned off (I thought they went back for sale like at the start of the game).

> Should you owe the Bank, instead of another player, more than you 
>   can pay (because of taxes or penalties) even by selling off buildings 
>   and mortgaging property, you must turn over all assets to the Bank. In 
>   this case, the Bank immediately sells by auction all property so taken, 
>   except buildings. A bankrupt player must immediately retire from the 
>   game. The last player left in the game wins.

Taken from the final Bankruptcy page from the offical [Hasbro Rules](http://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/00009.pdf)

I would add that I would treat the properties as unmortgaged for the purposes off re-selling them and deem that as the mortgage loan was owed to the bank, they would write off that debt if required.

Comment: Am I correctly reading this as a single auction happens for all property?

Comment: @ZAD-Man: It doesn't say, but as a matter of common sense I'd say no - the properties are auctioned off 1 at a time. Obviously any that are un-bought then go back up for sale at full price.

Comment: The bank doesn't write the mortgage off, it forecloses on the property. When the property was mortgaged, the bank paid out half the value of the property. When the player goes bankrupt, the bank gets the full value of the property. So it comes out ahead.

Comment: All the properties get auctioned off, even at $1 if that is all that is bid by a player remaining in the game.

Answer (score 2):

If you get the "bad" Chance or Community Chest card that has you owing more money to the the bank than you can pay, the bank is your creditor, and you must turn over your property "as is" to the bank, just like any other creditor.

The bank is unlike a "normal" creditor, insofar it gets to "unmortgage" your property for "free." The bank will auction your landed property as in "real life." The houses and hotels go back into the common pool of 32 houses and 12 hotels. If there is a "housing shortage," there might be a separate auction for those.

If you are alone against one opponent, you will lose the game immediately. If there are two or more, it shouldn't be hard to persuade at least ONE of them to bail you out by buying one key property for as much you owe or more. Ideally, you will have your opponents fight for the privilege of bailing you out. If you have to go down, go down, fighting, and at least try for the privilege of being "kingmaker" among your opponents.

Comment: There are 12 hotels in monopoly